# Moving OneNote in sharepoint using files explorer breaks Get pages

Tags: sharepoint, onenote, onenote-api

We moved OneNote hosted in SharePoint from one folder to other using file explorer (View in file explorer option). After the OneNote is moved it started looking like a folder instead of OneNote file and we don’t get the notebook which we moved in Get Note books API call. Accessing the one note from client works normally. It is just that OneNote which is moved is not listed in Get Notebooks API call. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I work on OS X so I hope this answer is relevant to your situation.
Uploading a notebook to SharePoint results in it losing "special permissions" and becoming just a regular folder (I think this is what is happening to you too).
The workaround I use is to create a new OneNote notebook with the same name and then copy the files from the old notebook to the new one and it will work again in the API.
The actual pageIDs will change as the new notebook has a different ID and you will have to reload the notebook in the OneNote app.
It would be great if there was a function in the API to download and upload Notebooks to Sharepoint, I put a suggestion into the OneNote API's user voice.